# Alternatives to openjdk-7-jre?

Tags: server, ssh, minecraft, putty, headless

Trying to build headless serv for minecraft w/ friends. I'm following a guide that wants me to install  openjdk-7-jre, however I noticed that people are saying it doesn't have updates anymore and to not use it. I want to know is there an alternative to that? or do I just have to have it?

Thanks.

Comment: Java installation options (minecraft did not install) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: For most distributions, it is recommended to install OpenJDK 16 (for 1.17+) or OpenJDK 8 (for below 1.17) https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Common_instructions https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/openjdk-16-jdk

Comment: My own Minecraft server has worked properly with the `openjdk-11-jre-headless` package for years instead of `openjdk-7-jre`. Next time I upgrade that container (in 6 months), I will test migrating to v16. Whatever 'guide' you are following seems suspect...or perhaps just old.

Comment: I see no OS & release details; so why are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may just have an old guide.

I've run a few servers over the last 9 years.

Unless you are aiming for a specific version of Minecraft you can likely get away with the latest version of Java.

I'm running a Paper and Vanilla server using `openjdk-17-jdk-headless`